# Angular custom directive dilemma

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating a website/app using angular, most of my requirements are being met by the Controllers calling the service and $resource for rest data fetch and show them using the template files through ui.router states.

Do i really need to code my display with custom angular directives. By not using the custom directives am i missing to utilize the power of angular ?

I looked at, the development of directives are having a steep learning curve, and not clear, is the time spent worth it.

Comment: Personally, I use directive mostly when I need some kind of custom attribute(expression) that can greatly enhance my html and css with JS. For example, it is fantastic for custom validations and such. Anything that would normally involve DOM manipulation in jQuery is a great use case. I also find it great for fast code re-utilisation.

Comment: This is really opinion based, but I will answer the best I can via a comment.  The the rule of angular directives is that if you are directly manipulating the DOM you should use a directive.  So if you wanted to do implement jQueryUI sortable, you should use a directive.

Comment: Also if there are things you will use more than once in your application, (such as menus, tabs, etc) you can creative directives that accept input attributes or use transclution to reuse markup and logic. You can then create your applications using these components, keeping things modular.

Comment: `am i missing the power of angular`... YES, You sure are!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great question, it has a lot to do with how you should be structuring your app in order to maximize the utility of Angular and the MVC that it provides.

The short:

Controllers, are generally meant for holding information to be displayed in a view, while logic inside a controller should be kept to a minimum. 
Whenever you're manipulating the DOM use Directives - and yes they are indeed worth learning.
Whenever you're updating data that can and will be shared across multiple facets of your website, use a Service.

The slightly longer version:

**Controllers**

Ultimately, controllers should have very little logic in them. You want to think of it as this bridge between your model and your view that just holds the information that is to be presented in your view. With that in mind, controllers should only be responsible for bringing logic together. Todd Motto who wrote the angular style-guide has an awesome blog post about it here: http://toddmotto.com/rethinking-angular-js-controllers/

**Directives:**

Directives are incredibly powerful in that they allow you to create custom elements with encapsulated logic. For example, let's imagine that you wanted to create a text autocomplete feature that will be used in many different portions of the website. Instead of having to recreate the html and logic/functionality surrounding an autocomplete many times over, you can create the "autocomplete" directive once, and with one line of html you can re-use it throughout your application. In turn, directives help promote the "Don't Repeat Yourself" (DRY) policy.

**Services**

Services are essentially your models in the application. Any time you're sharing data or data related methods across your application you should be using a service. Angular provides services (which are really providers at their core, but we won't get into that) so that you can share various methods and data sets across your application by simply injecting it. Just like Directives, they help you promote DRY as services are singletons meaning that each component dependent on a service has a reference to just one instance generated by Angular's service factory. Things that you might put in services are: http/api requests(whenever you're using an http services such as $resource, you should be using a service), utility methods(i.e. text formatting functions that you might be using in multiple places across the site), or any data that you will be displaying/utilizing in more than one view.